# Use full width of one component Angular2

Tags: html, css, angular

I wonder if anyone know how you set full width of one component with an background in Angular 2. Just want to use it on the home screen.

Following changes all the components so that doesn't work.

```
 encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ViewEncapsulation.None, then you can do it like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      Hello
    </div>
  `,
  styles:
  [
      'my-component { float:left;width:100%;padding:5px;background:#ccc;}',
      'html, body {margin:0px; }' 
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

See Plunker here:  https://plnkr.co/edit/b3jtpO5TAkV4eK0ZuR1k?p=preview

Comment: close, but It is still margins on left and right (because of my app.component i guess)

Comment: The margin is because the HTML and BODY tags need to have margin:0px :)

Comment: The margins wont go away with that either, have tried that already. :/

Comment: wops found the problem was in an other css file :)

Comment: hah, cool - i was going to send you this :) https://plnkr.co/edit/b3jtpO5TAkV4eK0ZuR1k?p=preview

Comment: Thanks anyway for the help :)